# getting current (system) day using an SQL query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this MySQl database that has a table which contains a column that contains days of the week like "Mon", "Tue" etc.

How do I get query the database and match this column content with the current (system) day?

like say

```
select .... where tablename.columnname = systemday
```

thanks.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
<?php 
$day=date('D');

$sql='select * from the_table where the_table.'.$day.'=systemday';
?>
```

Comment: incorrect SQL statement posted, should read "the_table.column = $day"

Answer (score 3):

Try using `date_format(now(), "%a")` as your condition value.

Read more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 1):

Haven't you tried searching ?

Anyways i hope you want something like this,

$cur_day= date('D');

`select .... where tablename.columnname = $cur_day;`

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE tablename.columnname = substr(dayname(now()),1,3)
```

or

```
WHERE tablename.columnname = date_format(now(),'%a')
```

Note, however, that it may be affected by locale settings.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday

```
Returns the weekday index for date (0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, … 6 = Sunday).
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek

```
Returns the weekday index for date (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, …, 7 = Saturday). These index values correspond to the ODBC standard.
```

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE dayOfTheWeek=WEEKDAY(NOW())
```

Also, you can do this using PHP`s [`strftime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) and [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) functions:

```
$query1 = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE dayOfTheWeek="'.date('N').'"');
$query2 = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE dayOfTheWeek="'.strftime('%u').'"');
```

But, I think, it is better to generate this in PHP-only way.